# write csv with encoding cp1252 with python 3.12

Tags: python, encoding, export-to-csv, cp1252

I import data from txt-files that are encoded in utf-8 and from xml files. Data from both formates are transformed and put separately in a pandas dataframe (one for the imported txt-file, one for the imported xml-file). Each dataframe is exported as txt-file. The problem is that these txt-files must be encoded cp1252. But they get coded in utf-8.

reading of xml files is done with

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    xml_file_path = path_files + xml_filename

    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
```

reading of txt-files is done with

```
import csv
            
with open(txt_filename, 'r', encoding=('cp1252')) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')       
    list_results = list(tuple(line) for line in reader)
```

non-cp1252 codable data are replaced with "?" using this code.

```
            def filter_cp1252(text):
                try:

                    encoded_text = text.encode('cp1252')
                    return text
                except UnicodeEncodeError:

                  
                    text2= ''
                    for nl, letter in enumerate(text):

                        try:
                            encoded_letter = letter.encode('cp1252')
                            text2 = text2 + letter

                        except:
                            text2 = text2 + '?'

                    return text2
```

Signs that are not cp 1252 are successfully replaced with "?". I could test this only when importing files as utf-8, but I let it in the code to stay on the safe side.

Data are collected in a list that is transformed to a pandas dataframe. After this export to txt is done with

```
df_import2.to_csv(output, header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode ='w', encoding = 'cp1252')
```

Nevertheless the output is utf-8 (and that drives me crazy).
Is there any suggestion, how I can solve my problem?

I have also exported the dataframe first to Excel and reimported with pandas hoping that this could solve the problem. But python obviously "prefers" utf-8 where ever possible.

Comment: First, it's unclear what the actual data is. Is it the dataframe? The text file? The XML files? Why do you want Latin1 anyway? Python strings are Unicode. The code you posted will *mangle* any text that isn't already in the Latin1 codepage. If the files are UTF8, use `open(txt_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`. If the text files are CSVs, use `pd.read_csv()` without any encoding. The default is UTF8 already

Comment: To export in Latin1 use `encoding='latin1` or `encoding='iso-8859-1'`. You can also use `encoding='cp1252'` BUT ... that's a Windows codepage and Windows is a natively Unicode OS, going all the way back to 1994. So why do you want to export to Latin1?

Comment: Did you try to open the CSV file in Excel by double-clicking, and got mangled data because the end user's locale settings don't match the file? Excel doesn't know what settings are used in the file so it uses the user's locale settings for the file codepage. In Windows 11 it may be 65001, ie UTF8. In older versions it usually matches the country's DOS codepage. The two easy ways to fix that is to 1) write directly to Excel with `to_xlsx`. That avoids all localization issues 2) Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'`. That emits BOM bytes that tell all editors what kind of Unicode encoding is used

Comment: Hi Thanks for the fast input. I need cp1252 encoding because the txt files are imported in a database and the interface just accept this coding. It is not my choice.

Comment: I tried to write with encoding latin1 and iso-8859-1, but created txt-files were utf-8 too.
I tried to replace to_excel with to_xlsx, but got an error message that the function does not exist.

Comment: That's probably not the case either. All databases support Unicode. And all have bulk import tools that can work with multiple codepages. It's still unclear what you're trying to do. Why not import the CSV files directly into the database? In any case, don't try to "fix" anything by hand and just specify the encoding you want in the *writer*, whether that's `to_csv` or something else

Comment: `but created txt-files were utf-8 too.` no way. What do you mean UTF-8 in the first place? All Western Europe alphabets use mainly US-ASCII characters with just a few characters outside the US-ASCII range. Did you *read* the files using the wrong codepage? Post actual code and file examples that reproduce the problem. The actual examples will show what actually happened.

Comment: In UTF8, non-US-ASCII characters are encoded as 2 or more bytes. In Latin1, the first byte is the same so it's easy to detect whether a UTF8 file was treated as Latin1 and vice versa.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks for all your input. I'm not experienced enough to understand all your comments. I will work on it and come back, hopefully with more precise questions and ideas -  maybe the solution.
What I understood now: Python always refer to the encoding of imported data. The argument encoding = 'cp1252' during export does not work in my case, even if all characters where checked to be encodable in cp1252 
(e.g.: df_import.to_csv(path + 'Output_Test_Results.txt', header=None, index=None, sep='\t', mode ='w', encoding = 'cp1252')

Comment: See [ask]. Post a [mre] and debugging details.

Comment: Why do you assume it didn't work? What did you actually see? Quite a lot of questions about "UTF8 encoding" actually mean escape sequences, not the real character to bytes encoding. `always refer to the encoding` no it doesn't, Python 3 strings are Unicode, period. `f all characters where checked to be encodable in cp1252` what you posted doesn't check that. It generates a file n Latin1, which is the more common name for CP1252. Any characters that can't be mapped are converted to `?`. If you see unexpected question marks it means the text *can't* be converted to Latin1 without losing data

Comment: Scandinavian and Eastern European characters are *not* in the Latin1 codepage for example. That's *precisely* why Windows uses Unicode natively and why you *shouldn't* use localized encodings

Comment: Typo: you are returning the original `text` instead of the `encoded_text`.

Comment: The Scandinavian characters å ä ö æ ø and quite a few more are all available in Latin-1 and code page 1252. These two are not exactly synonymous, though they share many code points.

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear and quite a lot of the code isn't useful. `open(...,encoding='cp1252')` would throw an error if the text was in the wrong codepage. To load characters that can't be mapped you'd have to use the [errors parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in open. If you use `errors='replace'` the characters will be replaced by `?`.

That means the non-Latin text comes from XML. Instead of trying to convert the text in code, you can use the [errors argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) in `to_csv` to replace non-Latin characters with `?` too.

Finally, you can use `read_csv` with `encoding='cp1252' encoding_errors='replace'` to read the text data directly into a dataframe.

```
var txt_frames=pd.read_csv(txt_filename,encoding='cp1252', encoding_errors='replace',sep='\t')
```

Once all frames are combined, you can save them as CP1252 with `encoding_errors='replace'`:

```
df_import2=pd.concat(all_frames)
df_import2.to_csv(output, encoding = 'cp1252', encoding_errors='replace', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
```

Comment: What's the suggested action in your first sentence? Does it serve a purpose or could it be removed? If it adds no value it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @TheLeb I suspect you didn't notice how the code contradicts the question, introduces the possibility of errors or how it's trying to replicate what `encoding` and `encoding_errors` do. We still don't know what the real question is. If you followed the comments you'd see that after a full day of asking for clarifications we got nowhere. At this point, it's better to just show a possible solution and wait for the OP to say "no, I meant that other thing" than keep trying to guess what the OP means by Unicode

Comment: Hi guys, my problem was solved. The proposal from @PanagiotisKanavos works as it should work. 
df_import2=pd.concat(all_frames)
df_import2.to_csv(output, encoding = 'cp1252', encoding_errors='replace', header=None, index=None, sep='\t')
But it works after changing the computer (both Win 10). On a Mac it works too. 
Lesson learned: There could be settings in the system environment that influence the desired output. For me it is case closed, I'm not able to dig dieper. Thanks for all input.

Comment: @Peter the real lesson here should be "stick to UTF8 everywhere".